# jQuery autocomplete cross site domain - listbox does not display

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete, cross-domain

I would like to use autocomplete with external data. I followed manual and data are smoothly returned, but listbox does not show. Could someone help me please?

This is my js:

```
$('.hledejNACE').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ac.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function( data ) { response( data ); }
        });  
    },
    minLength:1,
    select:function(evt, ui) {
        // when a name is selected, populate related fields in this form
        this.form.kodNACE.value = ui.item.kodNACE;
    }
});
```

Mozilla dev tools says, that data are successfully returned in JSON format.

This is my html:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    Name: <input id="hledejNACE" type="text" class="hledejNACE" style="width:250px;"/>
    Code: <input id="kodNACE" type="text" disabled />
</form>
```

I have linked these scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe I could help you if You would give me link to your testing server. It returns `json` or `jsonp`?

Comment: works at it should on Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer

Comment: But I don't see the listbox with returned values...

Comment: Hmm... it works on everything but not FireFox... that's pretty weird

Comment: There seems to be an error in jQuery... `SyntaxError: '*,:x' is not a valid selector` in `jquery-1.10.2.js` line `1639`...

Comment: I was wrong... I can't help you... :-( That's why I don't use FireFox...

Comment: I tried it on Chrome and IE, but it does not work either.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery?  Can you update?

Comment: Also, your jQuery UI JS and CSS versions don't match (1.12.1 vs 1.11.4) - why?

Comment: Well, it is from working (non-cross domain data) example..Also tried copy working example from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp and change ajax url, but still does not work

Comment: It works for me on Chrome (61.0.3163.100) and Opera (48.0.2685.52) and Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution:

You need to use callback in your PHP json return:

```
<?php

    $data = '{}'; // json string

    if(array_key_exists('callback', $_GET)){

        header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com/');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

        $callback = $_GET['callback'];
        echo $callback.'('.$data.');';

    }else{
        // normal JSON string
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

Thank you everybody for your effort!